# Possible to work with Isolated Storage from Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, silverlight

I'm needing to delete a value in Isolated storage from javascript code.

If this is possible how is it done? I found [some code from a post written in 2007](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2007/05/31/isolatedstorage-and-managed-javascript.aspx) and Silverlight has changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to call a Silverlight method from JavaScript.  This link provides examples on how to handle this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2007/06/01/call-scribtable-methods-from-javascript-with-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Expatiating Keith Adler's answer a bit...

IsolatedStorage can only be accessed by **managed code**, which is a term Microsoft uses to refer to code in one of the .NET languages. Fortunately, Javascript can be used to communicate with managed code, and vice-versa. As shown in the article you linked, this is done through a Silverlight object.

Microsoft has [a set of very detailed walk-through articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645031(v=vs.95).aspx) on this very topic. But perhaps you and others would prefer (or perhaps more appropriately, *would have preferred*) an existing solution over rolling out your own.

If that's the case, check out [BakedGoods](https://github.com/klawson88/Baked-Goods). Its a Javascript library that establishes a uniform interface that can be used to conduct common storage operations in all native, and some non-native storage facilities, including IsolatedStorage.

With it, you can accomplish what you want by using something like the following code snippet:

```
bakedGoods.remove({
    data: ["targetItemKey"],
    storageTypes: ["silverlight"],
    complete: function(byStorageTypeRemovedItemKeysObj, byStorageTypeErrorObj){/*code*/}
});
```

Oh, and for the sake of complete transparency, BakedGoods is maintained by none other than yours truly :) .